# table removing index path row values from array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, checkbox, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to create an array from selected table rows so I can push it to a new view. My issue is deleting an unselected row from the array it throws an error of index beyond bounds, although I have other items selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//listOfItems is a Pre Populated Array for the table 
    NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     
//the array i want my selected items to be added to  
     NSArray *array = names;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];



    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

   [names addObject:cellValue];

        NSLog(@"ARRAY: %@", array);

    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

             [names removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        

         NSLog(@"ARRAY: %@", array);  
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];


     } 
}
```

How do I find the index number in the array that is being created so it can delete the proper value? Any help would be appreciated :-) Thanks!

**-----SOLUTION-----** 
Here's an alternative way too just in case others were wondering.

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *selected = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

               [names addObject:selected];
             NSLog(@"ARRAY ADDED %@", names);
        }


   else {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;            

        [names removeObject:selected];   

        NSLog(@"ARRAY DELETED %@", names);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to pass an array of checked cell values to a view, why adding and removing objects at each cell selection? You could easily achieve this just before you're about to present the new view controller. Something like this:

```
// In whatever method you have to present the new view controller
// ...
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems.count; i++)
{
    if ([self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) //Change section number if not 0
    {
        [names addObject:[listOfItems objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

// Pass the array now to the destination controller
```

Ps. You still have to manage checking/unchecking of cells (just as you're already doing in the code above).

Comment: I need the array to add values into an sql statement.

Comment: @Far: okay... and what seems to be the problem using `names` array from my example?